# How do I compile simple gearman worker with C?

Tags: c, gcc, gearman

I am trying to compile a simple gearman worker on C. I use mac. Here is the code:

`#include <libgearman/gearman.h>
int main(void) {
    gearman_worker_st worker;
    gearman_worker_create(&worker);
    gearman_worker_add_server(&worker, "localhost", 4730);
    return 0;
}`

When I try to compile it with:

```
#gcc test.c 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gearman_worker_add_server", referenced from:
      _main in ccLUuf8y.o
  "_gearman_worker_create", referenced from:
      _main in ccLUuf8y.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know I have to link gcc with gearman but when try:

```
#gcc test.c -lgearman
ld: library not found for -lgearman
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install Gearman on your machine?  If so, where did you install it?  Since it appears you have the header, the library is probably around somewhere.  Did you specify a location to find the headers?  If you said `-I/some/where/include` for the headers, then you should probably say `-L/some/where/lib` to find the library.  I don't seem to have Gearman installed on my Mac; I know I've not installed it, and it doesn't seem to be in `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib` or `/Developer`.

Comment: I just found out port have not installed gearman properly. Installed it with brew and all works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe your need to define the lib path, like
`-L/usr/lib/`, use your libgearman.a stored path to substitute `-L/usr/lib/`

Answer (score 3):

maybe your need to define the "include path" and the "lib path",
for example,
the head file "libgearman/gearman.h" in the /usr/local,
the library libgearman.so in the /usr/local/libgearman/lib

the compile command like,
gcc -I/usr/local -L/usr/local/libgearman/lib test.c -lgearman

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://gearman.info/libgearman/gearman_worker_create.html), you have to link it with -lgearman

```
gcc test.c -lgearman
```